# LXDE - Use desktop as folder doesn't work

Tags: lubuntu, lxde

I'm using Lubuntu with LXDE UI. After system install I was able to enable "Use desktop as a folder" in Desktop Preferences. Then I was playing around with the settings and disabled it. Since then I'm not able to enable it again. When I click on the checkbox the Desktop Preferences dialog disappear immediately.

Is there any terminal command or configuration file which would enable this feature as well? Or where should I look for the error logs?

Comment: Not sure where the error log might be, I suggest you file a bug report against LXDE

Answer (score 1):

Right click desktop → "Desktop Preferences" → "Advanced" Tab.

Check the box for "Show menus provided by window managers when desktop is clicked".

Click Close.

Right click desktop again and choose "System" → "Restart OpenBox".

Desktop icons/settings should restore.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it does not solve my problem. I still get an internal error message when I enable "Desktop as a folder".

Answer (score 0):

It is late, but here is a solution for other people having this issue.

In some impossible way *Desktop Preferences* writes wrong profile for PCManFM: it adds a `folder=` line without any value for your currently active monitor. And after that it do not allow to switch *Use desktop as a folder* back ON.

LXDE starts PCManFM as:

```
pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE
```

The profiles are usually at `~/.config/pcmanfm/`.

So check your  `~/.config/pcmanfm/LXDE/` folder for `desktop-items-N.conf` files, where `N` is a number representing your monitor (I suppose).

For example, you might have something like `~/.config/pcmanfm/LXDE/desktop-items-0.conf` or `~/.config/pcmanfm/LXDE/desktop-items-1.conf`.

Open those files and remove the `folder=` line and save them.

Then switch *Use desktop as a folder* back ON in *Desktop Preferences*.